# How do i use Quotes inside of Quotes in C# and not let it error

Tags: c#, postgresql

Im trying to query some data from a postgres server using C#.

This is the code im currently working with:

```cs
    namespace WpfApp1
    {
        class postgresDB
        {

            public void Init_database()
            {

                NpgsqlConnection conn = new NpgsqlConnection("Server=FS01;User Id=postgres;" +
                                        "Password=pwd;Database=postgres;");
                conn.Open();
                Debug.WriteLine("DB opened");

                NpgsqlCommand cmd = new NpgsqlCommand("SELECT * FROM 'Users';", conn);

                NpgsqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                while (dr.Read())
                    Console.Write("{0}\n", dr[0]);

                conn.Close();
                Debug.WriteLine("DB closed");
            }

        }
    }
```

The Problem I have is that the SELECT query errors with this error:
`42601: syntax error at or near "'Users'"`

Im trying to do this in the first place because the postgres table name needs to be in quotes so it doesnt check the upper/lower case letters of the name. If i put the name in quotes it just skips that and finds the table anyways.

Comment: Try removing the single quotes around `Users` --> `"SELECT * FROM users;"`

Comment: @Fraser that's not relevant, that's about how to escape a *single* quote in SQL, this is the SQL query itself in C#

Comment: @Charlieface Yes it is relevant, your SQL has single quotes - `SELECT * FROM 'Users'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
string t = "SELECT * FROM \"Users\";";
```

or

```
string t2 = @"SELECT * FROM ""Users"";";
```

should work

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use \"

In most languages I came across \ is used as an escape character. You can use it to use quotes within quotes or alternatively add a new line with \n a tab with \t and many more things.

Fun fact if you want to use \ within a string literal you need to use \\